# OpenCSV vs regular FileOutputStream performance

Tags: android, performance, fileoutputstream, opencsv, file-writing

I'm trying to record Android's sensors data (e.g. 200HZ) in the phone's memory. I can use libraries like `OpenCSV`, just manually do that with `FileOutputStream`.

OpenCSV:

```
CSVWriter writer = new CSVWriter(new FileWriter("/sdcard/P.csv"), ',');
writer.writeNext(entries);
writer.flushQuietly();
```

FileOutputStream:

```
File file = new File(dir, "output.csv");
FileOutputStream f = new FileOutputStream(file);
```

What is the performance differences of these two options? Which one would better to use with high frequencies like this?